# Word order withと違う

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, particles, word-usage

In this sentence

> その点では私は君と意見が違う (My opinion differs from yours on that point)

As I understand, the first は (その点では) is optional because it puts emphasis on the phrase before it. The next thing is a special consturction XはYと違うwhich means "something is different from". However, I dont understand how 意見 works here in terms of grammar, because there is no connection between the words. Is it better to say 私と君との意見が違う or 私の意見は君と違う?

Comment: This might answer your doubt about how が is used with 違う: [Specifying what's different between two things, 違い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77125/43676)

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is perfectly natural. It can be understood as an extension of the "double-subject" construction (**Xは + Yが + predicate**), which is very common and natural in Japanese. Xは establishes the topic/scope, and Yが marks some property that belongs to X. In other words, you can think of Yが as "in terms of Y".

- 私は彼より背が高い。
- 彼女は僕より頭がいい。
- 妻は私と性格が似ている。
- 妹は姉と血液型が違う。
- LとRは発音が違う。

The following sentences are also correct, but these are less common in Japanese.

- 私の背は彼(の背)より高い。
- 彼女の頭は僕(の頭)よりいい。
- 妻の性格は私(の性格)と似ている。
- 妹の血液型は姉(の血液型)と違う。
- Lの発音とRの発音は違う。

(The words in parentheses are usually omitted; see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77404/5010))

Likewise, in 私は君と意見が違う, 私は君と違う says "I am different from you", and 意見が marks the "properties" of 私 and 君. 私の意見は君と違う is also perfectly correct but it's not really better than the original. You can also say 私と君とでは意見が違う or 私と君の意見は違う, but 私と君**と**の意見 makes little sense (it may mean "the opinion you and I made together" in some rare context).